# How can i write to a file my arraylist?

Tags: java

I make some changes in my arraylist. After I want to write to a txt file from my arraylist. But it write just onu line. I didn't get it.

How can i fix it?

This is my code

```
try {
    show_seats_write = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("d:/seats2.txt"),true));
                                                           System.out.println("Tickets size: "+tickets.size());
    for(int i=0;i<tickets.size();i++){
       for(int j=0;j<tickets.get(i).getlist().size();j++){
         show_seats_write.print(tickets.get(i).getlist().get(j));
             System.out.print(tickets.get(i).getlist().get(j));
             System.out.println();
             show_seats_write.println();
             show_seats_write.close();
        }
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {                                 
     e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing the PrintWriter after only writing one thing. Move `show_seats_write.close();` outside of your for loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
show_seats_write.print(tickets.get(i).getlist().get(j));
```

This line should either be;

```
show_seats_write.println(tickets.get(i).getlist().get(j));
// OR
show_seats_write.print(tickets.get(i).getlist().get(j) + "\n");
```

I think that should get your info onto multiple lines.

Comment: It didn't work. I try over and over. But in arraylist i can see the change.